# Copy Not Actually Copying Without Reference

Tags: python

I'm having trouble understanding why the eMaxHP keeps changing with the current HP, as indicated by the monster's dictionary containing HP.

```
import copy

monsterDict = {'hp':5}

class Battle(object):

    def __init__(self, monster):
        self.monster = monster

    def __str__(self):
        eMaxHP = copy.copy(self.monster['hp'])
        out = str(self.monster['hp'])  + "/" + str(eMaxHP)
        return out

    def damageEnemy(self):
        self.monster['hp'] -= 2

hi = Battle(monsterDict)
print(hi)
hi.damageEnemy()
print(hi)
```

In the end the monster health prints 12/12, when it really should be something like 12/30 if you've dealt 18 damage.

What can I do?

Comment: How should anyone guess what's in the dictionary? You need to provide a sample of code that is enough to demonstrate the problem (however, don't include your full solution - strip it of irrelevant parts).

Comment: questions here gets poorly received for a few main reasons: 1. not detailed enough. 2. not demonstrating actual use case and error (including backtracks). 3. not showing what have you tried so far. As long as you demonstrate these 3, you should not be received poorly and you will get answer.

Comment: Welcome; please read and follow the posting guidelines.  In particular, we should be able to paste your posted code into a file, run it with Python, and reproduce your problem.

Comment: monster['health'] is just a number, I just want a second copy that doesn't update along with the dictionary value, is that really that hard to do?

Comment: @AlexRosenbach Definitely it's not as simple as you claim it is. Numbers in Python are not references, so the behaviour you describe is impossible. Post a [mcve]!

Comment: We don't know what that value is... which is what makes this question difficult to answer. `copy.copy` does a shallow copy - which is fine if its really an integer - not fine if its a nested data structure. You could `print(repr(monster['health']))` to show its a number. Better, is an example we can run to see what is going on.

Comment: Think of it this way, there is something wrong in your code but we can't know what that is without your code.

Comment: Well, I guess it is a nested data structure, self.monster is an attribute stored in class Battle that's a dictionary, containing HP, Evasion, Attack, etc.

Comment: I'll add, I indeed did do the print(repr(self.monster['health'])) which gave it's value as a number, like I said.

Comment: Print it out and lets see! BTW, here is an example of a running verifiable example of your code... at least what I know about it... https://pastebin.com/sSiceRai. It doesn't fail. If you can write something like that but fails like your code, then we have good stuff to work off of.

Comment: @AlexRosenbach Stop describing your code, just show it ([mcve]). The question will be closed otherwise, and please understand - it won't be in spite of you, but because we are simply unable to guess what's the problem without seeing the code that contains the problem (the part you've shown doesn't).

Comment: Very well... I have no idea what the problem is so here's my code: https://pastebin.com/V3D99V02

Comment: @AlexRosenbach That's not how it works on SO. Please, if you want to contribute here, take some time to learn about SO's rules ([help]). Posting links to pastebin in comments is not the way to go. For the third time, please, click&read: [mcve]. You need to post the example in the question post itself.

Comment: In other words: please explain in your question, what is the minimal piece of code I should write on my laptop to observe the problem you have?

Comment: I tried... I did something similar to what tdelaney did, and it does indeed work. For some reason, it just doesn't work in my situation. If I could narrow the problem like it asks in the "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" then I probably wouldn't need help solving this issue. I'm not sure it's the fact that it's in the tostring or it's two modules interacting is the problem.

Comment: @AlexRosenbach Try removing the long `elif` chain - leave only one option, and see if the problem persists. Then remove parts of other functions that are not directly related to modifying/reading HP. Each time, verify that the problem still persists - and it will be small enough to include in the question. Don't forget to add a simple main script, or instructions on how do you run your program.

Comment: OK! Got a minimized example!

Comment: How can you have `12/30` when you start with `5` and subtract `2`? Why do you expect `eMaxHP` to be any different in value to `self.monster['hp']`?

Comment: Because it's a copy? Copied through the copy module? "eMaxHP = copy.copy(self.monster['hp'])"

The 12/30 part is irrelevant, I don't care about the numbers are, as long they don't change both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design is wrong. You don't keep monster's maximum HP anywhere. When you call `damageEnemy`, you change the **only** place where it's kept. Creating a copy in `__str__` doesn't help - yes, you're copying the value, but you do it at the wrong place.

Just to clarify:

1. Initially, you have `hp.monster = monsterDict = {"hp": 5}`. There is only one dict instance and both global `monsterDict` variable and `hp.monster` attribute reference it.
2. When you call `print`, you create a copy of this dict, use it to print "5/5", but you discard the copy as the method exits (it's just a local variable in your `__str__` method).
3. When you call `damageEnemy`, you decrement this value. But you have just one dict here, and you update it. At this point, there is no dict with `{"hp": 5}` left anywhere.
4. So when your `print` statement calls `__str__` again, the only thing exists is a dict with `{"hp": 3}`. This is why it prints "3/3".

You could've done it like this:

```
...
class Battle(object):
    def __init__(self, monster):
        self.monster = monster
        self.initial_monster = copy.copy(monster)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}/{}".format(self.monster["hp"], self.initial_monster["hp"])
    ...
```

(Be sure to check out what happens if you don't call `copy.copy` but just assign `self.initial_monster = monster`. Without `copy` you won't have two dict instances, but just one, referenced multiple times.)

Or you could've made a `Monster` class that keeps two values - which, I believe, makes more sense. Here's a rough sketch how I'd do this:

```
class Monster(object):
    def __init__(self, hp):
        self.hp = hp
        self.max_hp = hp

    def damage(self, hp):
        self.hp -= hp
        return self.hp

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}/{}".format(self.monster.hp, self.monster.max_hp)

class Battle(object):
    def __init__(self, monster):
        self.monster = monster

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.monster)

    def damage_enemy(self, hp=2):
        self.monster.damage(hp)

battle = Battle(Monster(18))
print(battle)
for _ in range(0, 5):
    battle.damage_enemy()
    print(battle)
```